Finding unique columns and their indices in NumPy matrix efficiently
I have a very large binary matrix (for example, shape = (210000, 5000)) and want to find unique columns and indices of this matrix. Memory is important to me, so that is why I am looking for a method that is more memory-efficient than np.unique().
I found the below code on Find unique rows in numpy.array. This method is indeed memory-efficient (though slower, which is not as important in my case); however, it finds unique rows (I need columns) and does not return indices of those rows in the original matrix.
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=np.byte)
# This method finds unique rows without indices (but I need columns with indices of unique columns).
ncols = data.shape[1]
dtype = data.dtype.descr * ncols 
struct = data.view(dtype)
uniq = np.unique(struct)
uniq = uniq.view(data.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)

Could someone help me with this?
The desired output for an example above:
Matrix with unique columns:
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

Indices of unique columns:
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]


(1) Just use the transpose of your matrix and then transpose the result. (2) You can get the indicies from the np.unique call.

@jared, unique takes an axis parameter, so the transpose isn't needed.  But unique uses sorting to put identical elements next to each othrr.

If you really need memory space, then you should pack bits. It takes 8 times less space which is pretty huge. It should also make operations more cache friendly. However, Numpy cannot directly operate on a compact representation (so it needs to be unpacked which is not efficient in term of memory space and performance). It might be a good idea to move away from Numpy if this is so critical for you.

@hpaulj Yes, but I was saying they can use the exact same code if they simply transpose the array and final result.

OP, the code you share only returns the rows that only appear once, and duplicate rows are not returned at all. The normal functionality of np.unique returns the unique set of rows (so if a row appears twice in the original array, it will return it once). So, which result are you looking for, the one that returns the unique set of columns or the one that only returns columns that don't have duplicates? It's not clear since you said you want something more memory efficient than np.unique, which implies that that function works but isn't efficient enough.

I think np.unique + np.argsort should work for you.

@jared I have updated the question with the desired output. As mentioned, I need a matrix where no two columns are equal to each other (columns 1 and 2 in the example). I know that I could achieve this with np.unique(data, axis = 1, return_index = True) but it makes a copy of an array internally which takes a lot of memory. The code that I have attached works with structured arrays. As you mentioned I tried using the transpose but it does not work as I expected and throws an error ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the last axis must be contiguous.

@JérômeRichard do you have any particular suggestions?

@farid_musa how many unique columns do you expect out of the 5000? I agree with Jérôme, you could use a more compact structure (if you have only 0/1, a boolean array will be 8 times smaller).

@mozway As an example, I have 969 unique columns out of 6376 or 2480 out of 15260. I agree that a more compact structure could work here. Do you have any suggestions?

Actually, your post seems very close to How to accelerate numpy.unique and provide both counts and duplicate row indices. It looks like the main difference is that you want to do that on columns so a transposition is needed before. What about trying this method?

An alternative solution is just to write a solution in a native language like C/C++ and operate on compressed representation directly (i.e. each booleans stored as 1 bit). This is optimal memory-wise. It may increase the execution time compared to a non-compressed fast code but you can mitigate this issue by using multiple threads. Such a solution should be much faster than any Python solution (Numba included). If you have really a lot of columns, then hashing may help. Note that doing that is not trivial, especially for non-skilled C/C++ users.

I'm not sure exactly about your ideal performance speed, but technically you could reduce the amount of processes in your code using pandas, I know the tolist part slows down the code, but it's a simple solution:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=np.byte)

s = pd.Series(data.T.tolist())
indices = np.where(~s.duplicated(keep='first'))
output = data[:, indices]

print(indices)
print(output)

Output:
(array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]


I have provided a desired output. I need a matrix where no two columns are equal to each other (columns 1 and 2 in the example) and the corresponding indices. Your proposed solution completely removes columns 1 and 2. Do you know if .tolist() still keeps data as bytes?

@farid_musa I fixed it! Pandas is way easier for these type of computations.

@farid_musa It will remain like bytes since at the end I'm still indexing the original numpy matrix, so nothing change with the dtype.

Unfortunately, your proposed solution is much more memory costly than just using np.unique(). That is one reason why I didn't want to go with pandas. Again, memory consumption is much more important for me that time.

You can use two dictionaries:

uset: records unique cols.
dset: records duplicate cols.

import numpy as np


def _unique(matrix):
    uset, dset = {}, {}
    for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        H = hash(matrix[:, i].data.tobytes())
        if H not in uset:
            uset[H] = i
        else:
            dset[H] = i
    for k, v in dset.items():
        if k in uset:
            del (uset[k])
    indices = list(uset.values())
    return indices, matrix[:, indices]


data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=np.byte)

print(_unique(data))


Prints
([0, 3, 4, 5] # indices

array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int8))


Isn't the last column duplicated as well?

The columns is full of 0s

Yes, shouldn't that be removed?

Ah understood, I thought it was the other way, would've nice if OP provided a desired output though

Yes, very much agreed.

@user24714692 I have provided a desired output. I need a matrix where no two columns are equal to each other (columns 1 and 2 in the example) and the corresponding indices.

@user24714692 It does not output a column  = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and its index 1. In your solutions, both of those columns are removed. Please check the desired output.

@farid_musa Do you only want the duplicate columns and indices? See? or Do you also want both duplicate and unique columns and both indices? See? if you only want the duplicate columns and their indices, this would suffice?

I think you can use unique + argsort like below
import numpy as np

val, idx = np.unique(data, axis = 1, return_index=True)
val[:,np.argsort(idx)]
idx[np.argsort(idx)]

which gives
[[1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]


[0 1 3 4 5]


I tried a similar solution. As mentioned in the question, for very large matrices, this becomes very memory costly.
